# AddView programmaticaly crop last view

Tags: java, android, view

I have `LinearLayout` in which i programmaticaly add some view. But last view which i add in `LinearLayout` is cut or small.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/inner_task_llContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_m"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_l"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
</LinearLayout>
```

Adding view:

```
llContent.addView(TaskUtils.createTextFieldComponent(requireContext(), task, llBottomSheet))
```

```
public static View createTextFieldComponent(Context mContext, ItemTaskDetail task, LinearLayout llBottomSheet) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view;
    if (task.getType() != TaskType.TXT) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_control_lable, null);
    } else {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_control_text_area, null);
    }
    return view;
}
```

[image]

Comment: @TheLibrarian In question i add xml of my LinearLayout .-.

Comment: picture is displays how the element is cropped. My fragment has this linearLayout and i add other view in LL programmaticaly. In this case LL is crop last view

Comment: @TheLibrarian looks strange, because if i add 3/5/10 more elements - all except the last one are displayed correctly

Comment: Well, that looks like padding issue, but first element is not cropped the same way?

Comment: no, first element is displayed correctly

Comment: Is the linear layout in a scroll view since you can add 10 more elements?

Comment: Looks like the `LinearLayout` is full and needs to scroll, but you aren't using a `ScrollView`.